# Microsoft Access 2000 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have query in access vba that i am looping through, the result is a name of a property and with this name i want to open up a report which uses a query with one parameter which is the property name.  The loop is fine the problem i am having is passing that parameter to the report in the loop. I have tried a few things but to no avail i keep getting a message to pass the parameter manually.  The loop is basically going to send a report to each owner of the property by email attachment.  When i do the report one by one with no loop it works fine but in loop it seems not to be picking up the property name.

Comment: Are you looking up the property name and then trying to loop through the property owners sending the same report to each one?

Comment: Hi, i am getting a result set first which returns a propery name ( house name ) and then with that result  i want to pass the property name to the report which i can then  email each owner the report within the loop.

Comment: If i do it manually through the form ( one by one ) it takes the parameter no problem.

Comment: You could test that the result set has a value by moving to the first record and set in a variable to that field.  Then pass the variable to the code like you do with the form.

Comment: site = [Forms]![frmRequestBookingsPaidOut]![sites].Value
 DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportBookingsForSites", acViewPreview  this is manually and it works fine. In the loop it keeps popping up a msgbox asking me to pass the parameter manually

Comment: are you setting the "site" variable before opening the report with vba?

Comment: Yeah "site = rs!SiteID" that is fine no problem it shows up fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need to do is loop through the query and open the report for each record in the query.  Something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim PName as String

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("Select * from YourQueryName")

Do While rec.EOF = False
  PName = rec("PropertyName")
  DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportBookingsForSites", acViewPreview, , , , PName
Loop

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

The reason you put PName in the OpenReport string is because you're passing what's called an "OpenArgs".  This allows you to open the report and use a variable.

In the OnLoad event of the report, put something like this:

```
Me.RecordSource = "Select * from Whatever where PropertyName = '" & Me.OpenArgs & "'"
```

That should do it.